# Заполнение полей на сайте с помощью Android приложения

Tags: android

В приложение по клику на кнопку выполняется такой код

```
Intent browserIntent = new
            Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://osagodo.agentapp.ru"));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Хочу сделать так, чтобы автоматом происходила авторизация с нужным логином и паролем. Как это можно сделать? Или лучше создать отдельное активити с webview и делать это с помощью loadUrl и javascript?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте webView:

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this);
setContentView(webview);
byte[] post = EncodingUtils.getBytes("postvariable=value&nextvar=value2", "BASE64");
webview.postUrl("http://www.geenie.nl/AnHeli/mobile/ranking/demo/index.php", post);
```

для этого вам нужно использовать определенный адрес [вот](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) статья по этой теме.